# Issues while adding new elements sub document operations

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am currently working with mongoDB where facing some issues with adding elements in sub docs. I have done something shown below.

### issue

When I add a new element the name field remains empty

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("595f63c45fe41321f7a0e23b"),
    "point": 0
}, 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("595f63d45fe41321f7a0e23c"),
    "point": 0
}
```

## My Model schema

```
var playerSchema = new Schema(
{   name           : {type:String},
    point          : {type: Number,default:0}
});

var matchSchema = new Schema(
{
    player_one     : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,required: true,ref:'Player'},
    player_two     : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,required: true,ref:'Player'},
    round          : {type: Number,required: true,default:0},
    winner         : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    loser          : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});

var tournamentSchema = new Schema(
{
    tournament_name: {type:String ,unique : true},
    tour_owner     : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,required: true,ref:'User'},
    players        : [playerSchema],
    matches        : [matchSchema],
});

var Tournament = mongoose.model('Tournament',tournamentSchema);
```

## My API

```
function addPlayerToTournament(playerName,tourneyName,cb) {
    getTourneyByName(tourneyName,tourneyDetails);
    function tourneyDetails(tourney) {
        tourney.players.push({player:{name:playerName}})
        tourney.save(function(err,result) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        cb(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance......

Comment: because it's `tourney.players.push({ name: playerName })`. Nothing gets written because the schema has no `"player"` property at the path you are referencing.